# Can information be extracted from a COUNT query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to extract information from a count query?

I'm going to be querying a lof of very big database tables as part of an online encyclopedia. It tentatively looks like I'll have to make at least three major UNION ALL queries.

The first query is a COUNT query to determine if a URL matches a value in my database and a page should therefore be displayed. The second query would probably target the field URL on each table and look something like this:

```
SELECT URL, 'World' AS MySection, 'GW' AS MySiteID
```

This allows me to assign a website and section ID to each database table. The third query would then group tables with the same website and/or section ID together and query them for additional information.

Anyway, I wondered if I could eliminate the second query by assigning site and section ID's in my count query. I think the answer is NO, but I thought I read somewhere that it can be done. Can anyone tell me how to do it, or is this a lost cause? The way I'm doing it below doesn't work for obvious reasons.

```
$sql = "SELECT
 SUM(num) AS num
FROM
(
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num, 'World' AS MySection, 'GW' AS MySiteID, gw_geog.`URL` as URL  
 FROM gw_geog
 WHERE URL = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num, 'World' AS MySection, 'GW' AS MySiteID, gw_geog_political.`URL` as URL
 FROM gw_geog_political
 WHERE URL = :MyURL
) AS X
WHERE X.URL like  :MyURL
LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $MySiteID = $row['MySiteID'];
 $MySection = $row['MySection'];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing a [GROUP BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) onto the "inner" queries? So, right after the WHERE on both "inner" queries put this: `GROUP BY URL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get rid of the count (its expensive as well).  And just get the two fields.  If they are null, then there is nothing to display.

Comment: Hmmm...that's an interesting suggestion. My pages are actually loading pretty fast even with all three queries, though I have more database tables to add to the query. I may mark this as the right answer; let me play around with it a little first. Thx!